# Limiting behavior of a function defined by a Lambert-type series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, tauberian-theory

Fix a positive real constant $\omega$, and let $\left\{ c_{n}\right\} _{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of real numbers so that the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_{n}}{n^{\omega}}$$ converges *conditionally* to a finite value $S$. Next, let: $$L\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\lim_{x\uparrow1}\left(1-x\right)^{\omega}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\frac{1-\left(1-x^{n}\right)^{\omega}}{\left(1-x^{n}\right)^{\omega}}$$ Is it true that $L=S$? That is, is the interchange of limit and sum:$$\lim_{x\uparrow1}\left(1-x\right)^{\omega}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\frac{1-\left(1-x^{n}\right)^{\omega}}{\left(1-x^{n}\right)^{\omega}}\overset{?}{=}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\lim_{x\uparrow1}\left(1-x\right)^{\omega}\frac{1-\left(1-x^{n}\right)^{\omega}}{\left(1-x^{n}\right)^{\omega}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_{n}}{n^{\omega}}$$ valid? I already know that this is true whenever the sum defining S is absolutely convergent. I've tried using a summation-by-parts argument to deal with the conditionally convergent case, which gives:

$$L-S=\lim_{x\uparrow1}\left(1-x\right)^{\omega}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(\frac{n+1}{1-x^{n+1}}\right)^{\omega}-\left(\frac{n}{1-x^{n}}\right)^{\omega}+n^{\omega}-\left(n+1\right)^{\omega}\right)\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{c_{k}}{k^{\omega}}$$ and I suspect that Dirichlet's test for series convergence—namely, that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}b_{n}$$ converges whenever the $b_{n}$s are a non-increasing sequence of real numbers that tend to $0$  as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and whenever the $a_{n}$s are complex numbers for which: $$\sup_{N\geq1}\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}\right|<\infty$$ but I can't quite see how to make the argument work.

Anyhow, how might I show that $L=S$ (using Dirichlet's test or some other method), or, is there a counterexample that will dash my hopes to pieces? If there is a counterexample, might there be some minor stipulation to be made for the $c_n$s so as to guarantee $L=S$?

Comment: It works when $\omega=1$ and $c_{n}=\mu\left(pn\right)$, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function and $p$ is a prime. So, clearly, there are non-trivial cases where it holds. The same choice of $c_n$ also works for various $\omega$ between 1/2 and 1 (where the flexibility of 'various' depends on the Riemann Hypothesis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it holds true. There's a known criterion of "regularity of Abelian summation":

> Let $f_n:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ meet $\lim\limits_{x\to b}f_n(x)=1$ for each $n$. Then, to have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim_{x\to b}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n f_n(x)$$ for any convergent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, it is necessary and sufficient to have $$\sup_{x\in(c,b)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\big|f_n(x)-f_{n+1}(x)\big|<\infty\tag{*}\label{maincond}$$ for some $c\in(a,b)$.

A proof is in section $4.7$ of *Divergent Series* by G.H.Hardy. We only need the sufficiency (which is fairly easy to prove, basically following your idea of summation by parts), but the necessity implies that we have *the only way* to go. So we check \eqref{maincond} with $(c,b)=(0,1)$ and $$f_n(x)=\big(n(1-x)\big)^\omega\big((1-x^n)^{-\omega}-1\big).$$ It turns out that $\sup\limits_{x\in(0,1)}=\lim\limits_{x\,\uparrow\,1}$ here, and a computation of this value (call it $S_\omega$) is **sketched** below.

> For a fixed $x\in(0,1)$, the map $n\mapsto f_n(x)$ is monotonic if $\omega\leqslant 1$ and [unimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality#Unimodal_function) if $\omega>1$.
> This implies  $\color{blue}{S_\omega=2L_\omega-1}$, where $L_\omega=\sup_{x\in(0,1)}\sup_n f_n(x)$, and $L_\omega=1$ if $\omega\leqslant 1$.

To show the above, in rough steps, we set $g_\omega(x)=(-\log x)^\omega\big((1-x)^{-\omega}-1\big)$ so that $$f_\color{blue}{n}(x)=\left(\frac{1-x}{-\log x}\right)^\omega g_\omega(x^{\color{blue}{n}}).$$ Now if $\omega>1$ then $g_\omega'(x)=0\iff 1-(1-x)^\omega=(-x\log x)/(1-x)$ has a *unique* solution $x=x_\omega\in(0,1)$ *[consider the "inverse" function $\omega=\omega(x)$]*, giving eventually $\color{blue}{L_\omega=g_\omega(x_\omega)}$.

And if $\omega\leqslant 1$ then $g_\omega'(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$ *[shown similarly]*, giving the expected $\color{blue}{L_\omega=1}$.

Comment: (Actually I computed $S_2\approx 2.02$, $S_3\approx 8.16$, $S_4\approx 38.5$ *before* obtaining the sketched results.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Funnily enough, I managed to prove the statement myself the same day as I posted the question, using Abel's summation method (re-writing the sum as an integral) and the Dominated Convergence Theorem. However, knowing that there's pertinent information in Hardy's book (which I have) is extremely helpful, so, thanks for that!